# Electronically Actuated DPDT Switch?

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller, powermosfet, dpdt, uav

I am trying to be able to dynamically switch two wires on a brushless motor ESC for a Quadcopter. The plan is to wire an arduino to the flight controller so that I can program it to switch the ESC direction when needed. The problem is that I don't know of a good way to do this. I could use two mosfets on each ESC, but I'm nervous because they're 20A ESC and I don't want to use heatsinks to save weight. I can't find suitably small DPDT relays that can handle the current either. Any ideas? Please note: I'm not an electrical engineer, but more accurately described as an electronically literate Aerospace Engineer, so if you can dumb down to my level, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A similar question was asked recently except the person wanted to use switches/mux to share a motor controller between multiple motors where only one would be active a time. The advice was still to have a motor controller for each motor.

Comment: Switching 2 wires on a BLDC motor would reverse it. If this is what you're trying to do, it would be simpler to use an ESC that can reverse already.

Comment: Switching a 20A motor with MOSFETs will probably burns the MOSFETS because of peak current far exceeding 20A. You must look at relay, I'm afraid. And even these relays must be powered with powerful MOSFETs or relay driver.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this. Bidirectional semiconductor switches that can handle the motor power are almost as much work and as large as the original motor driver itself. This is because the semiconductor switches that exist fall into two broad groups:

1. Can conduct current in both directions and interrupt current, but can only block current in one direction
2. Can block current in both directions but cannot conduct current in both directions and cannot interrupt current (once they start conducting they latch on so current must be interrupted by something else)

That means you need multiple devices just for a single bidirectional switch plus all auxiliary drive circuitry.

Far and away the best approach is to get an ESC that actually allows inherent reversing in software.

> I could use two mosfets on each ESC

No, you can't. This is wrong for two reasons:

1. MOSFETs fall into category #1 which means that just to connect or
   disconnect a single line with bidirectional currents, you need two back-to-back
   MOSFETs just to make a single bidirectional switch.
2. But you aren't just looking to connect or disconnect a line. You are looking to connect/disconnect a line from one destination and disconnect/connect it to another destination. That means you need two bidirectional switches (4 MOSFETs) to swap one line between two lines. And you want to do swap two lines which means you need 8 MOSFETs. That's more MOSFETs than are actually in your ESC (which needs 6; if you have more than that then they are just all in parallel in 6 different groups for higher current capability).

Comment: What about a relay? Especially if they don't have to interrupt a load, could in principle be pretty small.

Comment: @pericynthion OP said they could not find one smal enough as tends to be the case when a question like this is asked. But solid state devices are even bigger. A relay is the only reasonable choice to try and do this with.